# Docker compose - Knex migration environment variables and host issues

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, knex.js

I have a docker compose that creates a postegres image and another image to run the backend/apis. I have the dockerfile that build the backend and serves API and static files. However when I run knex migration, it is not able to locate the host.

This is the docker compose

```
version: "3"
services:
   postgres:
   container_name: postgres
   image: "postgres:latest"
   environment:
   - POSTGRES_USER=username
   - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
   - POSTGRES_DB=dashboard
   ports:
   - 5433:5432

  server:
    container_name: server
     depends_on:
       - postgres
    build:
      dockerfile: DockerFile
      context: "./"

     environment:
       DATABASE_URL: postgres

    ports:
      - 3333:3333
```

This is the DockerFile

```
FROM node:14 AS client
WORKDIR /app
COPY client/package.json client/package-lock.json .
RUN npm install
COPY client .
RUN npm run build

FROM node:14
WORKDIR /app
COPY server/package.json server/package-lock.json .
RUN npm install
RUN npm install knex -g
COPY server .
COPY --from=client /app/build public
EXPOSE 3333
RUN knex migrate:latest
RUN knex seed:run
RUN npm run start
```

and my knexfile.js

```
module.exports = {

  development: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      host: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
      ...
    },
```

I have 2 issues.

1. Environment variable is not being read from the knexfile.
2. If I put static values in the knexfile "localhost" and "5433" then I get ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5433 when I run migration.

How would you approach this? I am kind of new to this.

Comment: Not sure whats going wrong with your environment var, but you're saying you get ECONNREFUSED when using localhost hardcoded in knexfile, the database does'nt run on localhost in your container because it is running in an other container, try using http://postgres:5433

Comment: I tried. In the knexfile I put the image name like this
    connection: {
      host: 'postgres_db',
      port: 5433,

I am still getting #16 10.32 getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN postgres_db
#16 10.32 Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN postgres_db

Comment: It should not be the image name, but the service name as defined in the docker-compose.yml. So in your example just postgres

Comment: Yeah sorry misspelled. I am using the service name and still not finding it. I am guessing maybe the depends on is not working.